# Hosting WCF Rest Services in WPF Application

Tags: wcf, rest, hosting

Hi i have some REST services created with WCF Rest Started Kit and i need to host these services in a WPF app. can someone point in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are there any WCF hosting scenarios you understand, or do you just not know how to do the WPF scenario>?

Comment: i am trying this in a consol app but it seams that did not work. when i try to access the service with fddler i get a 501 error. i have a webHttp binding named profile and a service base address of http://localhost:8080.

WebServiceHost2 host = new WebServiceHost2(typeof(Service));
Console.WriteLine("Service is up and runing...");
Console.Read();

where Service is my service created with WCF REST Starter kit.

Answer (score 3):

There's a really good project in Codeplex called "WCF Guidance for WPF developers" which has white papers, articles, mini screencast to show you a lot of ways to use and leverage WCF if you're a WPF developer:

http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/

Not sure if they have anything on REST webservices - but go have a look!

For a series of intros to WCF REST Starter Kit services per se, go see the Pluralsight web site and their screencast series - excellent resources!

http://www.pluralsight.com/main/screencasts/default.aspx

Basically, hosting a WCF REST service in your WPF app is no different from hosting any other WCF service, so I do believe all the excellent Pluralsight screencasts on hosting your own service should definitely give you a heads-up on how to proceeed!

Marc